# Xamarin.iOS WebView disappears after 10th reload

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I got a basic WebView in Xamarin.Forms like this:

```
<WebView AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 1, 1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" x:Name="ChartWebView" Style="{StaticResource BackgroundStyle}">
     <WebView.Source>
          <HtmlWebViewSource Html="{Binding ChartHTML}" />
     </WebView.Source>
</WebView>
```

I use the WebView to display a Chart.js diagram which works perfectly fine. On my page i got a button where the user can request data.

```
private async Task RequestData()
{
    //Doing some stuff to get data ...
    BuildChartHTML();
}

private void BuildChartHTML()
{
    var html = GetChartJSConfigString();
    Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
    {
        ChartWebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
        {
            Html = html
        };
    });
}
```

However, on iOS only, everytime on exactly the 10th request/reload the WebView gets blank. It also stays blank after that. I need to re-navigate to this page to get it up and running again. I tried adjusting the height on `WebView.Navigated` as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48981867/xamarin-webview-usually-shows-nothing) thread, without success.

The problem doesn't accure on Android with the same code base.

Open to any workarounds if this is a framework bug.

PS: I obviously made sure that the html I'm loading is not broken. I loaded the same data 10 times and i compared the html loaded on the 10th time where the WebView broke. It was exactly the same HTML string.

Comment: Since it doesn't work only in the 10th time . I don't think the issue is caused by your code . You could post the issue to github https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/new/choose . We will follow up it .

Comment: i found out the bug is not xamarin related but i will post a xamarin based solution as an answer for anyone else struggling with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem with iOS `WKWebView` and the use of HTML `canvas` (chart.js is renderered on a canvas).

After debugging into my WebView (stupid me not thinking about that possiblity before), i found out that the canvas memory exceeded the limit. With the help of a solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52532614/total-canvas-memory-use-exceeds-the-maximum-limit-safari-12) i managed to avoid this problem.

Keep in mind this solution is a little bit hacky. Basically what I've done is, as pointed out in the link above, i "deleted" the canvas everytime i reload my chart. By "deleting" i mean setting the canvas to `width` and `height` to zero. Applied to my code the solution looks like this:

Inside my javascript that runs in the browser i added a function like this:

```
function deleteCanvas() {
    //Get the main canvas where the chart is rendered to
    var chart = document.getElementById('chart'); 
    chart.height = 0;
    chart.width = 0;
}
```

And then everytime i call my `BuildChartHTML()` function i call this method in my c# code like this:

```
Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
    ChartWebView.Source = new HtmlWebViewSource
    {
       Html = html
    };
    ChartWebView.Eval("deleteCanvas()");
});
```